# Task scheduler not running after DST time change

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I'm experiencing problems with windows task scheduler since last DST change on the 28th (I'm in Europe).

I have serveral windows 10 PCs used as test bench, the program we are testing has a database and a function that allows the user to schedule a backup of the database. All tasks scheduled by the program have stopped since sunday, other scheduled tasks are running fine.

Scheduled tasks are created using `TaskService` class as follows

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    td.XmlText = xmlString;

    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(name, td);
}
```

The XML used for task definition is like

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>
<Task version=\"1.2\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task\">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>[RegistrationDate]</Date>" +
    <Description>[ScheduledTaskName]</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>[StartBoundary]</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <[DayOfWeek] />
          <[DayOfWeek] />
          ....
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions>
    <Exec>
      <Command>[Command]</Command>
      <Arguments>[Arguments]</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I have full control on PCs so I can confirm that they were properly connected to AC and the user was logged in.

Yesterday evening I have used the program to create again the scheduled tasks on a single PC. When the operation is performed previous tasks are removed and a new set of tasks is created. After this operation all scheduled tasks on this specific PC started running regularly.

I can't come up with a reason why my tasks have stopped with the DST time change. I think the issue may lie somewhere in the configuration as all other scheduled task are running fine.

Is there something that I've not taken into account with the configuration? Or some other operations I should have performed while scheduling the operation?

Comment: Did you try to reboot?

Comment: @harrymc I've perfomed a shutdown every evening and started the system in the morning but I haven't performed a reboot. I'll give it a try. I also hope this is not the solution as I won't be able to have a solution applicable to the program I'm testing.

Comment: It might be enough just to restart the involved services.